# как выйти из вложенного цикла, и при этом остаться в главном цикле

Tags: c++

хочу реализовать выход из из цикла for, но при этом не выходить из цикла while. Код:

```
while (True){
//какой-то код
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
//какой-то код
        if (что-то произошло)
        {
             //выход из цикла for 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а про  break  забыли?

Answer (score 5):

место строки "выход из цикла" поставить оператор break;

Answer (score -1):

Лучше поставить "что-то произошло" в дополнительное условие цикла for

Comment: Не лучше, а хуже.

Comment: @Qwertiy очевидно лучше, break это признак плохого кода

Comment: Не согласен. Флаги - признак плохого кода, а break - хорошего.

Comment: @Qwertiy какие флаги? в цикле for специально есть место для условия завершения цикла, там и нужно его писать. break же по сути аналогичен goto

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/417261)

Comment: @Coder всё содержится -_-

Comment: @user360745: Каким образом вы собираетесь писать это условие в заголовок цикла, если до начала работы цикла значение этого условия ещё не известно - оно анализируется и формируется нетривиальным образом в теле цикла. В заголовок цикла можно вынести лишь тривиально проверяемые условия. Все более сложное будет проверяться в теле цикла и при необходимости делать именно `break`. И это правильно. В заголовке цикла принято описывать лишь общий домен цикла. Завершение до достижения конца общего домена лучше делать через `break` - это существенно удобочитаемее.